# Chrome content_script isn't triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, that is supposed to do some basic DOM injection, However I'm having difficulties accessing the webpage from the extension, since the content script isn't triggering. Neither is there an output on the console, nor is the data being injected.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "[REDACTED]",
    "description": "[REDACTED]",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches": ["https://projects.[REDACTED].com/[REDACTED]"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service_worker.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

main.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App'

debugger;

// Inject Root
const app = document.createElement('div')
app.id = 'react-root'

console.log("main");
alert("main");

debugger;

document.body.appendChild(app);

const container = document.getElementById('react-root');
export const root = createRoot(container!); 

root.render(<App />)

debugger;
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import "react-dom";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

function useMutationObserver  (
  ref: any,
  callback: any,
  options = {
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  }
)  {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(ref.current, options);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [callback, options]);
};

function App() {
  const [mutState, setMutState] = useState(false);

  function _injectElements() {
    document.getElementById("newtaskheading")!.innerHTML = "<div id='inject-here'></div>";
    const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("inject-here")!);
    root.render(<Tasks></Tasks>)
  }

  useMutationObserver(document.getElementsByClassName("slideFormName")[0], () => {
    if (mutState == true) {
      setMutState(false);
    } else {
      setMutState(true);
    }
  });
  return (
    <h1>E</h1>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: May be the error is in content_script.js or service_worker.js? How does they look?